# How do I restart a settimeout loop javascript after being cleared?

Tags: javascript, slideshow, settimeout

I've been having an issue with some code that I wrote for a pure javascript-css tuorial. I'm a newbie to javascript, and I wrote this code to practice, but I think it would be perfect for some work I'm doing for a client. To change the slides, I have five function, the first is initiated onload, and then I use settimeout to do the next, and the next, and the next until 5, when it loops back to one, and goes in an endless loop, until the user presses pause (cleartimeout). My problem is, how do I restart the settimeout loop while staying on the current slide (function)? Note: I really want to stick with javascript for now, so I'd rather not have a jquery solution.

If you want to see the slideshow in action: http://fudgepants.com/beta/slideshow/
and you can view the source code there by pressing F12.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a separate function that controls which function to call. Let's call it showNextSlide().

This function would have a bound variable that cycles from 1 to 5. It calls setTimeout() on itself and to resume you just have to call that function again because it would still know where it left off.

```
// keep a reference to the most recent setTimeout() call
var timeOutId;

function showNextSlide()
{
    // initialize the bound variable for the first time
    // this variable gets preserved upon subsequent calls
    this.idx = this.idx || 0;

    switch (this.idx) {
        case 0:
            // code to show slide 1
            break;
        case 1:
            // show slide 2
            break;
        // etc.
    }

    // increase the counter and make sure it doesn't go over 4
    // i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
    this.idx = (this.idx + 1) % 5;

    // call me in 5 seconds
    timeOutId = setTimeout(showNextSlide, 5000);
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I don't get how to go about doing it.

Comment: @user1338292 Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but what's a bound variable, and also, I don't understand the code. I get the switch part, but not how the variable cycles. Should I, like, write an array of 1-5 or something. I just don't get it. Sorry for the total lack of understanding.

Comment: @user1338292 so the percent sign and then the number is like saying while(this.idx<=5), kidna.

Comment: Sort of. if (idx + 1 == 5) idx = 0; else idx++;